# Will I get Moksha if I commit suicide?

Tags: shiva, puranas, ramayana, moksha

Ramayan preached by Sri Chaganti Koteswara Rao garu. As per Ramayan, those who listen to Ramayan will get Moksha (Phala sruthi I.e. fruits of listening). Not only the one who listened, family member before and after 7 generations of the person so listened will also attain Moksha. So, if a person who listened commit suicide, will such person get Moksha?
Or if a person commit suicide in Kasi, will such person get Moksha. As it is generally told that a person who dies in Kasi will get Shivaikya (Moksha and Parvati matha will let the person dying in Kasi sleep on her lap, Lord Vinayaka will assist Parvati amma by giving last breath with his trunk).

Comment: This is complicated .. dying of course is not the same as committing suicide

Comment: Read the answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20750/5620

Comment: Person who listens Ramayana *properly* will never suicide. Hanuman in Sundarakanda says that life is important.

Comment: Persons who listen to Ramayana with almost devotion and is following Satya-Dharma will lead to Moksha. Following Dharma is central everywhere.

Comment: Those who commit suicide in Kashi will not get Moksha but instead they get Bhairava Dhandana (punishment). One can never get Moksha by suicide.

Comment: See 10th sloka http://www.valmikiramayan.net/sundara/sarga12/sundara_12_frame.htm

Answer (score 9):

**Or if a person commit suicide in Kasi, will such person get Moksha?**

In ***Chapter 26***, Description of Manikarnika, Kasi Khanda Purvardha of Skanda Purana, Sri Vishnu says Self-killing is not allowed at Manikarnika Ghat and it cannot bestow Moksha.

> 74-76. Let those other rites (Sandhya Prayers, holy ablutions,Tarpana, excellent study of Vedas,etc) too, performed excellently and with
>   **faith**, be the bestower of salvation. **Barring Prayopaveśa (fasting unto
>   death), no one shall indulge in self-killing**. O Išana, let those rites
>   be the cause of ultimate salvation. After performing a noble rite even
>   on some other occasions, the devotee should neither boast about nor
>   regret it. O İśa, with your blessings let all those holy rites bear
>   everlasting fruits here. O iša, with your grace let everything
>   concerning him be of never-ending benefit.

So, at Manikarnika of Kashi above rites bestow Moksha but not suicide. One must live with Dharma as mentioned in many chapters of Kasi Khanda of Skanda Purana to get Moksha in Kashi. Also, one can  clean off sins only if they take dip in Ganga [with faith and devotion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28110/3500).  Hindu scriptures never recommend Suicide. [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20750/3500) explains punishments for Suicide.

Comment: very precise find ... thanks to the Purana too for mentioning everything clearly this time . because sometimes they don't

Comment: @Rickross I remember this chapter particularly as i observed "Self killing" when i was reading for first time.

Answer (score 1):

No, committing suicide wont grant you Moksha, rather you will lose a human birth, and Supreme God almighty wont be happy on you for losing a human birth.
Remember human life has 4 phases, Dharma, Artha, Kama and than Moksha. You cant get Moksha without following **Dharma(Brahmcharya), Artha+Kama(Grihasta+Vanprastha) and finally Sanyasa(Moksha).**

Only Sanyassis can attain Moksha and they are given only one Mantra that is Om. That is why its written in Upanishads

[Kaivalya Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachiketa)

> The sound Om! is the syllabus of the supreme Brahman
>
> The Atma, whose symbol is Om is the same as the omnipresent Brahman. Smaller  than the smallest and larger than the largest, the Soul is formless and all-pervading.
>
> After death, it is the Atma that remains; the Atman is immortal.
>
> Mere reading of the scriptures or intellectual learning cannot realize
> Atma.
>
> **One must discriminate the Atma from the body, which is the seat of
> desire.**
> **Inability to realize Brahman results in one being enmeshed in the cycle of rebirths. Understanding the Self leads to moksha**

Comment: If we commit suicide we don't lose human birth, in fact we are born again as human being but under similar conditions, probably more severe.

Answer (score 0):

According to a quotation we find in the Sri M darshana by Swami Nityatmananda, only jnanis are allowed to destoy their bodies : अनाशके वा अपां प्रवेशे अग्निप्रवेशे वा महाप्रस्थाने वा ie by giving up food, immesing in water, self-immolation or going to the hills and die. The Vedanta-Guru of Sri Ramakrishna tried to get Himslf sunk in the ganges, but failed. Many monks,maccording to the above mentioned book, used to sacrifice their bodies in these ways.But all these were done by the jnanamargi monks. Pavahari Baba, the great saint by gazipur is known to have destroyed His body by Self-immolation.

According to Sri Ramakrishna, committing suicide is a grave sin, which results to being born again and again (Kathamrita, page 114,18 December 1882).

He also mentions it that without the knowlege of God, there can be no moksha (Kathamrita page 414, 28 Nov 1883).